# How to quantize all nodes except a particular one?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tensorflow` Graph Transform Tool to quantize the graph using

```
input_names = ["prefix/input"]
output_names = ["final_result"]


transforms1 = ["strip_unused_nodes","fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)",  "fold_batch_norms",  "fold_old_batch_norms","quantize_weights" ]

transformed_graph_def = TransformGraph(graph.as_graph_def(), input_names,output_names, transforms1)
```

I use the option `quantize_weights` to quantize the weights in graph, I know that certain nodes can remain unquantized by changing threshold `minimum_size` in `quantize_weights`, so leaving some nodes unquantized is certainly possible.

I want to quantize the weights of all nodes except a particular node with the name K or a set of nodes that have a name in K(set). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the previous answer refered to Tensorflow Lite code. I updated it to refer to Tensorflow.

Looking at the implementation of [Tensorflow's quantize_weights](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/quantize_weights.cc), these are the instances where weights don't get quantized:

1. tensor that is not type float
2. tensor that has fewer than 1024 weights (or another number specified by the parameter `minimum_size`)

If you are able to modify nodes in the graph so that they are excluded by one of the above rules, then quantize, then revert the nodes to the pre-quantized state, you might be able to do this.